# Subversion committing uncommitted changes to a new branch

Tags: svn, branch

I should have taken a branch to start with but decided to work on trunk instead, and now I want to create a branch and commit my uncommitted changes to that branch instead of trunk.

Is there an easy way to do that in svn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the switch command to switch your working copy the branch and afterwards you can commit the changes you made to the branch. But don't mix changes for trunk/branches.
Do the following in your working copy:

```
svn switch URL/branches/BRANCHNAME
```

and after changing do the commit.

Comment: Switch was giving some weird errors, but I tried creating a patch and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the direction though.

Comment: Wouldn't switch overwrite or conflict with local changes?

Comment: @Abidi: Yes of course if you have uncommitted changes in your working copy.

Comment: @khmarbaise re: Abidi's comment, isn't switch to a branch WHILE having local changes the exact question that was asked? And your response to Abidi says they will be lost aka overwritten?